# Build “rock, paper, scissors” in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is the code. Build “rock, paper, scissors”

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice = "rock";
} 
else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";
} 
else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1,choice2) {
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!"
}
else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "rock wins"
    }
    else {
        return "paper wins"
    }
}     compare(userChoice,computerChoice); //I forget to add it. Now I add it.
```

I don't understand why I need to add `else { return "paper wins" }`

Comment: but where is `userChoice` used? where are you calling `compare` method?

Comment: @programfighter, if `choice2 != "scissors"` then `choice2 === "paper"` only and besase `else { return "paper wins" }`

Answer (score 0):

the `===` operator is the [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) operator in javascript.  The `if` statement in question is doing a comparison on `choice1` and the string literal `"rock"`.  if that answer is true then the next `if` statement is executed and the program checks to see if `choice2` equals `"scissors"`.  if this statement is true than it returns `"rock wins"` because as everybody knows rock beats scissors.

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If `choice1` is `"rock"` and `choice2` is not (`else`) `"scissors"` then `choice2` could have either been `"paper"` or `"rock"`. Since there is no tie, `choice2` cannot be `"rock"`, so `choice2` is `"paper"`, and `"paper"` beats `"rock"`, so `"paper wins"`.

**EDIT**

Since the `return` statement immediately quits the function in case that

```
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "rock wins" // <-- quit the function
    }
    // <-- if you got here it is not true that (choice2 === "scissors")
    return "paper wins"
```

it means that you **can** avoid the `else` and just `return "paper wins"`

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why I need to add else { return "paper wins" }

It is because you have 3 different situation for this game which are(lets say i choose rock):

1. Opponent chooses rock => Draw
2. Opponent chooses scissors=> I win
3. Opponent chooses paper=> opponents wins